# Changing padding on hover to PictureBox dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, events, picturebox

A `PictureBox` is added dynamically to the form:

```
PictureBox image = new PictureBox();
//setting image properties...
image.MouseHover += ImageHover; //also tried MouseEnter
image.MouseLeave += ImageLeave;
Controls.Add(image);
```

And the event methods:

```
private void ImageHover (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((PictureBox)sender).Padding = new Padding(7);
}
private void ImageLeave (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((PictureBox)sender).Padding = new Padding(3);
}
```

Now the event doesn't *always* trigger. It does, but in a weird way (like when I <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> back to the form and when the form images load).

I thought of putting the events in a `Thread`, but I have no idea how to call `delegate` instances (called methods) as `Thread`s.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you are testing it correctly? I can't see any changes with padding, but it works fine when I change the image itself

Comment: Have you added child controls in the picturebox?

Comment: @EduardoWada yeah, weirdly enough, if I switch `((PictureBox)sender).Padding = new Padding(3);` with something like `((PictureBox)sender).ImageLocation = "image.jpg";` it works, but it's still delayed for a second (I guess until the image is loaded), what child controls are you referring to?

Comment: if you have something like `image.Controls.Add(new Panel()
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            });`, it will interfere with the mouse enter/hover/leave events, and I'm asking this because the Padding property does NOT affect the image

Comment: @EduardoWada Nah, nothing like that... I'm copy-pasting the full list: `slike[i, j] = new PictureBox(); slike[i, j].Location = new Point(sirina * j + offsetX, visina * i + offsetY); slike[i, j].Size = new Size(sirina, visina); if (Baza.Slike.Count > k) slike[i, j].ImageLocation = Baza.Slike[k++].Putanja ?? ""; slike[i, j].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage; slike[i, j].Visible = true; slike[i, j].Padding = new Padding(padding); slike[i, j].MouseHover += ImageHover; slike[i, j].MouseLeave += ImageLeave; Controls.Add(slike[i, j]);` It's messy here, but that's all. (slike[i, j] == image)